# use the git tags within powershell

Tags: git, powershell, tags, continuous-integration, azure-devops

We are using git & VSTS fro our CI/CD, also we got some guideline from our development team regarding the git's tags.

if we are going to deploy the code somewhere then we need to add a tag tat follow this format :
"Environment ver version"

for example:
prod ver 1.0.23 
tst1 ver 2.0.45
tst2 ver 2.0.46
dev ver 2.0.47

I like to have a script that read the tag (only in the latest commit) and writes a message

$tag  = SomeHowGetTheTags()

```
if ( $tag -like 'dev*')
{
Write-Host "this is for the development Environment "
}
```

- Question:
  How can I get the latest tags from git and ignore the historical tag? like the tags from last week or yesterday.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 4):

Last tag in the current branch:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

Latest annotated tag in all branches:

```
git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`
```

Comment: cool - the first one is what I need, any idea how to assign its value to a PowerShell variable?

Comment: I am not a powershell programmer (not a Widows user at all) but isn't it just `$var = git describe --tags --abbrev=0`?